# Comparison of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

How can I find the same values in the columns regardless of their position?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one':['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E', np.nan, 'H'],
               'two':['B', 'E', 'C', np.nan, np.nan, 'H', 'L']})
```

The result I want to get:

```
    three
0   B
1   E
2   C
3   H
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact logic is unclear, you can try:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'three': sorted(set(df['one'].dropna())
                                   &set(df['two'].dropna()))})
```

output:

```
  three
0     B
1     C
2     E
3     H
```

Or maybe you want to keep the items of col two?

```
out = (df.loc[df['two'].isin(df['one'].dropna()), 'two']
         .to_frame(name='three')
      )
```

output:

```
  three
0     B
1     E
2     C
5     H
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(set(df['one']).intersection(df['two']), columns=['Three']).dropna()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Three
1     C
2     H
3     E
4     B
```